# How to control vertical text alignment in HTML input field

Tags: css, forms, input, fonts, text-alignment

I faced with obstacles aligning the text in form input basing upon the size of font.

[image: difference between field inputs]

*URL: http://go.ruslanchik.ru/

NB: you should switch to "Ж/Д билеты"*

Great thanks for further helping.

UPD: I hope, it will clarify the situation.

[image]

Comment: can you please provide the code on jsfiddle? It would be better to understand and modify your code.

Comment: I don't see what you are desiring, the form on the link you provided looks very 'normal'

Comment: It appears normally in Chrome. In Safari it appears wrongly.

Comment: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrw0expj/ .

Comment: I think this is also font related...

Comment: Looks good on safari-mac.

Comment: you can fix this with css by using line-height. Than set the line-height to the font-size

Comment: Have you tried a combination of equal `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` and `line-height: normal`?