# Input text size and alignment in Safari Browser

Tags: css, alignment, textfield, forms

I faced with obstacles aligning the text in form input basing upon the size of font.

[image: difference between field inputs]

*URL: http://go.ruslanchik.ru/

NB: you should switch to "Ж/Д билеты"*

Great thanks for further helping.

If it's unclear, I hope, this picture will clarify the task.

[image]

--

It appears normally in Chrome. In Safari it appears wrongly.

JsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/mrw0expj .

Comment: Seems fine to me on the link, try alter `line-height` of the input field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Field input alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634225/field-input-alignment)

Comment: use line-height or padding-top:0px and add you wanted height for input box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y219bzt3/ i dont think it is possible to remove  full spacing